# Dynamically update AngularJS component definition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for a way to dynamically update a component, I have an object containing the information about the component (name, functions, variables, services, template, bindings, etc.). Then I generate the component dynamically using this data. And I need to regenerate the component whenever the definition is changed.

```
angular.module('components', [])
  .component('dynamicComponent', {
    bindings,
    template,
    controller
  })

angular.module('app', ['components'])
```

Is there a way to update the component that has been already registered on a module? or is there a way to update the module itself?

so far I've tried recreating the `components` module like so:

```
angular.module('components', [])
  .component('dynamicComponent', {
     ...newData
  })
```

but nothing happens.
I also tried recompiling the element after I recreated the module. Still nothing happens.

I also tried calling angular.bootstrap after creating the modules but I found out that is not possible without destroying the element bootstrapped. It's throwing an error saying the element was already bootstrapped.

My goal here is to dynamically update the component definition, on the fly, without reloading the page.

Comment: Components can only be added during the config phase of the app. Once the app enters the run phase, components can no longer be added.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the code of the component you want to modify and what the modifications would be (approximately). I can imagine ways to do something like what you ask for but I don't know if they would fit the behavior of your component.

Comment: @VirgilioGM the component and the modifications could be anything. it's not just one property or function of the component. I'm looking for a way to somehow unload the component and then bring it back dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by destroying the bootstrapped element, recreating that element, and calling `angular.bootstrap` again with the new updated modules and components.

Here's an example,
The initial code:

```html
<body>
  <div id="app" ng-controller="MainController as $ctrl">
    <dynamic-component data="$ctrl.data">
    </dynamic-component>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
angular.module('components', [])
  .component('dynamicComponent', {
    bindings: {...},
    controller,
    template
  })

angular.module('app', ['components'])
  .controller('MainController', ...)

angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app'), ['app'])
```

And to update `dynamic-component`,
reset and destroy the bootstrapped element. Doing so will enable us to call `angular.bootsrap` on this element again

```
document.body.innerHTML = `
<div id="app" ng-controller="MainController as $ctrl">
  <dynamic-component data="$ctrl.data">
  </dynamic-component>
 </div>
`
```

Define your modules.
Here, we can update the old `dynamic-component` however we want to. We can also add more components or modules.

```
angular.module('components', [])
  .component('newDynamicComponent', {
    bindings: ...newBindings,
    controller: newController,
    template: newTemplate
  })
angular.module('app', ['components', ...otherModules])
  .controller('MainController', ...)

angular.boostrap(document.querySelector('app'), ['app'])
```

Working [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MkSNF0S4EWuUReuYRgUA?p=preview)

If there's a better way, please let me know.